# c++ const argument passing: why compilers do not automatically set to pass-by-reference

Tags: c++, constants, pass-by-reference

I learnt that for non-primitive-type constant arguments it is more efficient to pass them into functions as references than as values:

- not efficient version:

  void funcA(const std::string myString)
- efficient version:

  void funcA(const std::string& myString)

Since the efficient version seems to be an obvious choice, I wonder why C++ compilers do not just automatically optimize this way for the not-efficient version?

Comment: Nothing is ever entirely free. When you pass by reference, you cannot assume any longer that yours is the only view of the data. Which may inhibit the compiler from optimizing away access.

Comment: Such an "optimization" may change the meaning of the program. `funcA` may be calling another function, which may modify the original string. The first version would not observe this modification, the second version would.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I tried "funcA calls another function, which modifies the original string" for both versions of funcA but none of them was compiled. Something like void funcA(const std::string& myString) {changeMe(myStr);} Error: binding ‘const string {aka const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ to reference of type ‘std::__cxx11::string& {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&}’ discards qualifiers

Comment: @Mako [Something like this](https://godbolt.org/z/9T5xx1367)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks for the code example. Now I understand your first comment.

Answer (score 2):

There are optimizations even in case of [copies](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision). Yes, in general, the compiler is required to make a copy when a function parameter is passed by value *(so there is no connection between the local copy and the outside (original) object)*. Compiler is also allowed to **elide the copy**, means to use the original object itself, when the source is an rvalue.

> Don’t copy your function arguments. Instead, pass them by value and
> let the compiler do the copying. - [cpp.next.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20140113221447/http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/#fnref:saks)

*"By value"* and *"by reference"* have **difference of semantic nature**. And the "optimization" we get from passing by reference is more of a consequence then a destination, one that is derived from the logic and meaning of the we express in the program.

Also, consider that even if in this scope the reference is `const`, we **still have a reference** (to another, independent object). Means that this object can still be modified by some external (to our scope) forces.

In the end, we should first strive for clarity of our expressiveness in the language, not to seek [premature optimizations](https://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: I think for some void funcA(const std::string& myString), the *logic and meaning* we want to express is: the input parameter is a constant, the function should/can not change it. The added "&" is just an optimization for performance. When a reference really "can still be modified by some external (to our scope) forces", I guess that would harm the original *meaning*. However, I could not figure out a real example where some external sources modify the variable. Anyone can give an example?

Comment: @Mako If there are more that one execution thread operating on same object (I do mean protected and valid use, imagine a lock shared by two threads). Yes, a reference helps to avoid copying if it is not needed, but it's nature is not to be an optimization technique. Optimizations comes later.

Comment: in the comments below my original question IgorTandetnik gave the following example: https://godbolt.org/z/9T5xx1367 . Your example with threads help too. Now I see cases where a reference can be changed outside the function which takes it as a constant. And I keep believing it's dangerous to use passing by const reference ... it helps to avoid copying but it may break the true meaning (a constant) we want to express for the function argument. I don't think whoever wants to specify a "const" when it might be changed. Can anyone enlighten me?